# Mapas en android studio

Tags: android, edittext

¿se puede introducir una dirección en un edittext y verla en un mapview en android studio?

Quiero introducir una dirección en un edittext y verla en un mapview, pero no se si eso se puede.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Intenta describir cual es el problema que estás enfrentando, y cómo has intentado solucionarlo hasta ahora con ejemplos en código. Puedes guiarte leyendo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: PD: Si, seguramente se puede

Comment: Se puede absolutamente todo lo que pienses. O introducir una dirección y mostrarla en el mapa o dada tu localización obtener la dirección. Inténtalo como te dicen los compañeros y si tienes algún problema comenta lo que has intentado y tu error.

Comment: Claro que se puede, revisa https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Places

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se puede lo que comentas, para esto debes usar [**Google Places API**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Places)

Puedes crear un [AutoCompleteAdapter](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Route-Google-Maps/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgesys/searchaddress/PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.java) para que al escribir una dirección esta sea buscada directamente en los lugares definidos en Google Maps.

Puedes agregar un `EditText` para escribir una dirección y el autocomplete generaría la dirección y posteriormente el punto en el mapa.

Este es un ejemplo de una aplicación para escribir 2 puntos, fuente y destino y genera la ruta entre los 2 puntos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tú respuesta fue de mucha utilidad.